# c# stack queue combination

Tags: c#, stack, queue, containers

is there in C# some already defined generic container which can be used as Stack and as Queue at the same time?
I just want to be able to append elements either to the end, or to the front of the queue

thanks

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Check the [LinkedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx) class.

```
LinkedList<int> list = new LinkedList<int>();

list.AddFirst(1);
list.AddLast(2);
list.AddFirst(0);
```

Answer (score 13):

Here's my implementation of an *immutable deque*:

http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2008/02/12/immutability-in-c-part-eleven-a-working-double-ended-queue.aspx

Notice that this is an *immutable* double-ended-queue. Normally you probably think of a queue as something you mutate:

```
queue.Enqueue(10);
```

An immutable queue always stays the same; when you add a new element, it gives you back an entirely new queue, so you use it as:

```
queue = queue.Enqueue(10);
```

if you no longer care about the old value.

Comment: With all due respect, this doesn't appear to answer his question.

Comment: The link has a class that defines what the OP was looking for.  The example given in this answer doesn't really show that though.

Comment: StriplingWarrior, I have no idea what you're talking about. The poster asks for an existing generic container which acts like a stack or a queue. Such a container is called a "deque", and I provided a link to source code for an implementation of such. Exactly which part of the question was not answered?

Comment: DeQueue is the right name here, LinkedList is 1 possible implementation of a DeQueue.

Answer (score 4):

What you want is a [linked list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx) - there's one in the BCL - that has [AddFirst](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132170.aspx) and [AddLast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132175.aspx) methods

Answer (score 3):

Here's a class to help people implement this easily:

```
public class StackQueue<T>
{
    private LinkedList<T> linkedList = new LinkedList<T>();

    public void Push(T obj)
    {
        this.linkedList.AddFirst(obj);
    }

    public void Enqueue(T obj)
    {
        this.linkedList.AddFirst(obj);
    }

    public T Pop()
    {
        var obj = this.linkedList.First.Value;
        this.linkedList.RemoveFirst();
        return obj;
    }

    public T Dequeue()
    {
        var obj = this.linkedList.Last.Value;
        this.linkedList.RemoveLast();
        return obj;
    }

    public T PeekStack()
    {
        return this.linkedList.First.Value;
    }

    public T PeekQueue()
    {
        return this.linkedList.Last.Value;
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return this.linkedList.Count;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `Enqueue(T obj)` method call `AddLast` instead of `AddFirst`?

Comment: @YehorHromadskyi it's implemented as enqueing at the front of the linked list and dequeueing at the back. I don't see a mistake, but let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: You're right, my mistake, sorry for confusion.

Comment: @YehorHromadskyi it's no problem!

Answer (score -1):

Good old `List<T>` will do it.

`Add()` to enqueue, `Insert(0,T)` to push, `Remove(0)` to pop/dequeue.

Comment: Insert and Remove will both be O(n) operations. A linked list will be O(1)

Comment: Cool - my first downvote. Thanks for pointing out the O(n). But to be picky, wouldn't it only be O(n) on inserts to the front of the List but not to the end (since it's Array-based)?

Comment: That depends on which cost you are referring to. Are you talking about the *amortized* cost, or the *worst single case* cost? The amortized cost of inserting n items into the end of a double-when-full list is O(1). The worst-case cost of inserting one item int a double-when-full list of n items is O(n).