# C# - Java's Deque

Tags: c#, deque

in Java, there's a class called [Deque](http://www.jdocs.com/javase/7.b12/java/util/Deque.html), and i would like to find something similar to this in .NET (C#).

The reason i need this, is because i need to peek the last item in the collection, and then dequeue the first one in the collection.

Thanks,
AJ Ravindiran.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[PowerCollections](http://www.codeplex.com/PowerCollections) has a Deque class (and a proven pedigree).

Comment: What does this offer above LinkedList<T>?

Answer (score 10):

Check out .NET's [System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0) collection, which can be used as a Deque. It's a doubly linked list.

Insertion/Deletion

- [`AddFirst`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1.addfirst?view=net-6.0#system-collections-generic-linkedlist-1-addfirst(-0)): Add to beginning
- [`AddLast`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1.addlast?view=net-6.0#system-collections-generic-linkedlist-1-addlast(-0)): Add to end
- [`RemoveFirst`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1.removefirst?view=net-6.0#system-collections-generic-linkedlist-1-removefirst): Remove from beginning. Does not return value.
- [`RemoveLast`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1.removelast?view=net-6.0#system-collections-generic-linkedlist-1-removelast): Remove from end. Does not return value.

Peeking:

- [`First`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1.first?view=net-6.0#system-collections-generic-linkedlist-1-first)/[`Last`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1.last?view=net-6.0#system-collections-generic-linkedlist-1-last) Properties.

  These Return a `LinkedListNode<T>`, not the actual value. To get the value you have to add `.Value` to the end.

Answer (score 2):

List should do that for you:

```
var l = new List<int>();
var last = l[l.Count - 1];
l.RemoveAt(0);
```

Comment: As a temporary workaround would do. Problem: RemoveAt(0) takes O(n) time.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my implementation of a `Deque<T>` (using a ring buffer) and a concurrent lock-free `ConcurrentDeque<T>`:

- Github: https://github.com/dcastro/DequeNET
- NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/DequeNET/

Both classes support Push, Pop and Peek operations on both ends of the deque, all in O(1) time.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this was touched on [in another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798348/c-stack-queue-combination) .

The popular answer seemed to be settling with a linked list, and Eric Lippert suggested his own [Deque implementation](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2008/02/12/immutability-in-c-part-eleven-a-working-double-ended-queue.aspx).

So I guess the short answer is no, there is no such strict data structure built-in in .NET

HTH.

Comment: It should be noted that Eric's Deque implementation is an immutable collection. If immutability is not important to you, then there may be more efficient mutable deque implementations.